# Bootstrap 4 - border color for a specific cell in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to apply border color (red) for a specific cell and it seems like the color is not applying to top and left side of the cell.

Looks like the border color of other cells are overriding the color that I am trying to apply.

```css
.border-red
{
 border:red solid 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
<div class="col-6">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 1</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 2</td>
<td class="border-red">90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 3</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know your suggestion to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have `border-collapse: collapse;` change it to `border-collapse: separate;` (coming from Bootstrap `.table` class) and add `border-spacing: 0;` if you don't want the gutters between cells.

```css
table.table {
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0;
}

.border-red
{
 border:red solid 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
<div class="col-6">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 1</td><link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<body>
<div class="col-6">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 1</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 2</td>
<td class="border-red">90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 3</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 2</td>
<td class="border-red">90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Test User 3</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add display:block; style, and you will be good to go.

```
.border-red
    {
     border:red solid 1px !important;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work fine. I am doing further testing with that. Thanks.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh be careful change the display to block from its default display table-cell... you will unable to do things like `vertical-align: middle;` since its no longer a table cell. This is more of a hack

Comment: @zgood, i just observed that. Also, applying the above css for empty cells seems like not fitting correctly.

Comment: The above only works when you apply it to a single cell. If you try this with multiple cells it will totally screw up your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Remove class of `border-collapse: collapse;` and Replace It with `border-collapse: separate;`